Does the C compiler have to short-circuit && and || unnecessarily?
C short-circuits && and ||.

Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second operands. If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

We often use this in idioms like
bool xyz = ptr && *ptr == 42;
But suppose we have very simple operands to the || operator:
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
[ ... other code ... ]

int myFunc() {
  int x = a[0] == 1 && a[1] == 2 && a[2] == 3;
}

It seems that if C must guarantee the latter operands are not evaluated, it has to generate something like (forgive my freehanding of poorly-remembered assembly pseudocode):
  xor   eax, eax
  cmp   a+0x0, 0x1 ; a[0] != 1
  jne   end
  cmp   a+0x4, 0x2 ; a[1] != 2
  jne   end
  cmp   a+0x8, 0x3 ; a[2] != 3
  jne   end
  mov   al, 0x1    ; all equal, set 1
  
.end:
  ret

That seems like a lot of branches! My general intuition is that unnecessary branches are bad, because we hit branch prediction issues. (In the past, I have replaced branches with statements like a && b, thinking it would remove the branch! Granted, I think it also makes the code clearer in most cases.)
Here's what I'd expect the non-branching version would look like, and my intuition says we'd prefer this in most cases. (again, forgive the freehand x86):
  xor   eax, eax
  xor   ecx, ecx
  cmp   a+0x0, 0x1 ; a[0] == 1
  sete  al
  cmp   a+0x4, 0x2 ; a[1] == 2
  sete  cl
  and   al, cl
  cmp   a+0x8, 0x3 ; a[2] == 3
  sete  cl
  and   al, cl
  ret

This feels like it is equivalent and removes the branches. (Though maybe loading a page into cache is "side effects" enough?)
I suspect I could encourage the compiler to generate this assembly by making my && into &? However, in general, my experience is that I should trust the compiler to optimize things better than I can.

Is the compiler required to generate "short-circuit" machine code if there are "no" side effects?
Is there a way to let the compiler decide whether to use an early-out or a non-branching strategy?
In practice, should this affect how I use & and && in parts of my code?

Related:

Is short-circuiting logical operators mandated? And evaluation order?
Is it safe to check if a pointer is null, then dereference it in the same if statement?


In your example, the short-circuiting is required, as not doing it could result in accessing the array out of bounds, which causes undefined behavior.  Optimizing away the branches is only legal if the compiler can know that the accesses will not cause faults that would not otherwise be possible.

@ChrisDodd Suppose a is fixed-length and defined globally, so it's in .data and the compiler can reason about it. I'll add that to the question.

if the compiler has the information, then it can do anything it wants as long as the visible result of the code will match what the exectution semantics of the source specifies.  Whether any given compiler will do any given optimization is a toss-up.

Seems to me that you already know the answer as you mention "side effects". That's the answer... The C standard doesn't care how the visible results are generated. It only cares about the visible results being correct. BTW: No, loading data into the cache is not a visible side effect.


In practice, should this affect how I use & and && in parts of my code?

No it should not.  You should write you code in the clearest and most humanly readable form.  Microoptimizations like this should only be undertaken if and when profiling of the code has revealed a performance issue.

Is the compiler required to generate "short-circuit" machine code if there are "no" side effects?

The compiler is required to generate code that has the same visible effects as short-circuit code in the source.  As long as it has enough information to know that is the case, it can generate any code it wants.

Some current machines will treat short forward conditional branches like this as essentially "conditional skip" instructions -- that is, they'll execute straight through the whole block of code without executing ANY branches (or consuming branch prediction resources, which are precious) and just supress the instructions that should be skipped by the branches.  To take advantage of this, you might see code generated where each 'jne' branches to the next 'jne' instruction -- so it would appear to be quite suboptimal, but when executed turns out to be very fast.

"The compiler is required to generate code that has the same visible effects as short-circuit code in the source." That's the thing though, the OP's 2nd example executes those side effects regardless of the result of the previous calculations. So there will be branches. Latest gcc and clang for x86 both generate code similar to the OP's 1st example.

@Lundin huh interesting. that could be a good answer maybe? I guess the question is, are gcc and clang generating that bc they think it's faster or because it's required?

The conditional skip you mentioned (Chris) is a cool example as well and might explain why the compiler chooses to generate jne's in Lundin's case.

@Kaia: If the branches are 100% unpredictable the branchless code is likely an improvement. But remember, most branching is fairly predictable (that's a major part of why branch prediction is worth the effort). I'd be interested to see if gcc/clang ever generate branchless code, e.g. if you engage PGO and feed it workloads that make the branch highly predictable vs. highly unpredictable, will the latter trigger branchless &-like code that does "more work" but thanks to lack of side-effects, is indistinguishable from the official && behavior?


This feels like it is equivalent and removes the branches.

It is not. You execute the right operands of the && regardless of what the previous results were. None of the mainstream x86 compilers generates code like that because they respect the "short circuit" behavior.
It's always a touchy subject when the compiler's optimizer changes the meaning of the code, compilers avoid that. Rather they seek to omit things from the C code that fill no purpose and that's also how the C standard itself defines optimization too (from C17 5.1.2.3):

An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and
that no needed side effects are produced

In your specific case the compiler could omit the right operands of && if it can conclude that no side effects are present there. However, it cannot know at compile time which operands that are zero and non-zero, so it will have to execute the code for all operands of the && until it hits a zero. And then it must stop, as required by the && operator (C17 6.5.13):

If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

Running your first example on latest gcc x86 -O3 (or equivalent clang), I therefore get similar code to your first asm example:
myFunc:
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rdi], 1
        je      .L6
.L1:
        ret
.L6:
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rdi+4], 2
        jne     .L1
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rdi+8], 3
        sete    al
        ret

Changing the C code to int x = 0 && a[0] == 1 && a[1] == 2 && a[2] == 3; gives the expected optimization to just return zero no matter what:
myFunc:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret

If modifying that expression to contain a side-effect somewhere in the right operands, then it is still not evaluated.



Is the compiler required to generate "short-circuit" machine code if there are "no" side effects?


It is not allowed to change the meaning of the code regardless of side effects. It cannot execute code that was otherwise left out. It is also not allowed to re-order the evaluations because the && operator comes with a sequence point.


Is there a way to let the compiler decide whether to use an early-out or a non-branching strategy?
In practice, should this affect how I use & and && in parts of my code?


Well... maybe. && is well-known to cause extra branches and using & is a known way to manually optimize code to reduce branches. Whether or not we should manually optimize code to begin with is the big question. The rule of thumb is that we shouldn't do so unless we have spotted a real bottleneck in the program.
But lets give swapping && for & a try (and note precedence == over &):
int myFunc(int a[]) 
{
  int x = a[0] == 1 & a[1] == 2 & a[2] == 3;
  return x;
}

Does this asm look familiar? (gcc 13.3 x86 -O3)
myFunc:
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rdi], 1
        sete    dl
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rdi+4], 2
        sete    al
        and     edx, eax
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rdi+8], 3
        sete    al
        and     eax, edx
        ret

It did the very optimization you suggested. This is much more efficient code.
clang did something even fancier without any cmp at all:
myFunc:                                 # @myFunc
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rdi + 4]
        xor     eax, 1
        xor     ecx, 2
        or      ecx, eax
        mov     edx, dword ptr [rdi + 8]
        xor     edx, 3
        xor     eax, eax
        or      edx, ecx
        sete    al
        ret


Thanks for the answer! I'm trying to understand how @ChrisDodd and your answers fit together or if they disagree. Is it that compilers could generate the non-branching version (under the 'as-if' rule/'same visible effects') but, de-facto, that level of rewriting is considered too close to changing meaning and so clang/gcc/etc make a point of respecting sequence points for optimization? Or does the 'as-if' rule not apply here?

@Kaia I don't think they fit together. Writing the code as readable as possible with && means that all mainstream compilers respect the purpose of the code, not evaluating the right operands. Which in turn does lead to branches. The only way to get rid of the branches is to change the code. I think the fact that gcc generated nearly identical code as your handcrafted asm when I switched to & is proof that gcc could do that optimization but chose not to. It's not so much about sequence points as not evaluating the right operand in case the left one is false.

The second example is equivalent to
x = ((a[0] ^ 1) | (a[1] ^ 2) | (a[2] ^ 3)) == 0;
because the array indices are known to be valid and the array elements are initialised. It would be valid for uninitialised array elements if uninitialised elements on a particular implementation behave as if they had an unspecified value, not undefined behaviour.
So evaluation without short circuiting would be possible and would be done by a good compiler if it was faster.
